# Visualisation of connections - python, R, matlab?

Tags: python, r, matlab, visualization

I am trying to find a tool for visualisation of connectons between specific points. I have a bunch of data points which are sometimes connected with each other, I want to create a map of this connections - maybe something like this:
[image]

Do you have any tips or suggestions for such a tool? Perhaps there is a module or function in python, R or matlab that can accomplish that task.

Comment: the igraph package for R or the python networkx module are good places to start, but those had to have come up in a google (or even SO) search. you could also just use gephi as that requires no programming skills.

Comment: looks like a GraphViz problem - look at the pydot module, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot

Comment: GraphViz is definitely one I'd recommend.  Here's an implementation in MATLAB where someone has tried to mimic what it looks like completely self-contained within MATLAB: http://matlabtools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/graphics/drawGraph.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more information on LinkedIn InMaps (closed down Sep 2014):

http://www.quora.com/What-graphing-algorithm-does-Linkedin-inMaps-use

> The layout is an optimized Barnes-Hut algorithm, and the colors are
>   picked using the Louvain optimization for modularity.  While we
>   definitely played around with Gephi for some earlier mocks of the
>   project, the final version does not use it.
>
> InMaps uses Hadoop/Pig , Ruby , Voldemort, Java and Processing for the
>   heavy backend maps calculation and image processing. The exploration
>   widget is powered by Javascript and open-source libraries Seadragon
>   and RaphaelJS.

Mathieu Bastien, one of the core programmers, has a tech presentation here:

http://www.slideshare.net/linkedin/linkedin-meetup-inmaps

and he is also a core programmer for Gephi, an open-source graphing GUI:

https://gephi.github.io/